# CSS .current_page_item

Tags: css

I found something like

```
#nav ul li.current_page_item a {background: #4654FF;}
```

I have researched and could not found what that `.current_page_item` does?
Will really appreciate some help.

Comment: it's a class name, used to specified which object you're targeting

Comment: It is a class selector. See this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) for guidance

Answer (score 2):

.current_page_item looks like the class of a specific li element, for example the mark up would look like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a href="#">some line</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So in a nav situation it might be applying a class to the "current page" the user is on, to highlight to the user what page they are on.

Answer (score -1):

**.current_page_item** is the selected item, or is the page at the moment. Ex: it's on **page 2**, where you could have 1-**2**-3.

```
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a href="#"> item </a>
</li>
</ul>
```